# Bold or slanted tipa characters with mathpazo package in pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, tipa, mathpazo

When using `TIPA` with package `mathpazo`/`pxfonts`, bold and slanted IPA characters are not generated. In the MWE below, excluding `mathpazo` will generate bold/itlaics/slanted characters.

[image: with mathpazo][image: without mathpazo]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % or pxfonts

\begin{document}
  \textipa{\:l} \textbf{\textipa{\:l}} \textit{\textipa{\:l}} \textsl{\textipa{\:l}}
\end{document}
```

The following warning messages are shown

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/ppl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 9.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/ppl/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 9.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/ppl/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 9.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/ppl/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 9.
```

First, `T3/ppl/m/n` is substituted with `T3/cmr/m/n`. This is expected. But the next 3 (`T3/ppl/b/n`, `T3/ppl/m/it`, and `T3/ppl/m/sl`) are replaced with `T3/ppl/m/n` and not their `cmr` counterparts.

`TIPA` has boldface fonts. How can I can use them?

Comment: Try package [`tipauni`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipauni). It is developed precisely for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute Domitian, which like the `mathpazo` text font is based on Adobe Palatino, but supports IPA symbols.

In PDFTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T3, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{domitian}

\begin{document}
\noindent
  l \textbf{l} \textit{l} \textit{\textbf{l}} \\
  \textipa{\:l} \textbf{\textipa{\:l}} \textit{\textipa{\:l}} \textsl{\textipa{\:l}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Domitian sample]

### Original Answer

This is a side-effect of legacy 8-bit font encodings. One way around it is to use a Unicode-enabled engine with a version of Palatino and Asana Math, which are based on Young Ryu’s `mathpazo` fonts.

In PDFLaTeX, you can fall back on the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{T3}{ppl}{ptm}

\begin{document}
  \textipa{\:l} \textbf{\textipa{\:l}} \textit{\textipa{\:l}} \textsl{\textipa{\:l}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This declares the Times font (`ptm`) as the substitute for Pazo’s text font (`ppl`) for the `T3` encoding.  It won’t quite match the main text font, a Palatino clone, but there are a very limited number of fonts for this obsolete 8-bit encoding.

Comment: If adhering to the main font is a necessity and using Unicode engines can be considered, then [`newcm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newcm) is also worth mentioning. With the latest version (2023-01-02) a lot of new characters have been added to the IPA set.

Comment: See: https://texdoc.org/serve/newcm/2#section.11

Comment: @Niranjan Actually, it looks like Domitian should work.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you so much. This works. And I learned something new today! `substitutefont`!
@Niranjan Thank you for your responses. I just want to add that `tipauni` uses `fontspec` and doesn't work with pdfLaTeX. The publisher that I'm submitting to only has `pdfLaTeX` and hence the need for `TIPA`.

Comment: @Navi I don’t think I mentioned `tipauni`, but you can definitely use that together with `unicode-math` in XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: @Davislor `tipauni` was regarding @Niranjan's comment (not under your response, but under the post question).

As a follow up question to using substitutefont, how would it work when we've boldface inside italics (or the other way)? `\textit{\textbf{\textipa{\:l}}}`
I get an error, `! No declaration for shape T3/ptm/b/it.` and tried `\substitutefont{T3}{ppl/b}{ptm/b}` and `\substitutefont{T3}{ptm/b/it}{ptm/b/sl}`
Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: @Davislor OK, `\textsl{\textbf{\textipa{\:l}}}` works.

Since `ptm` doesn't have italics `T3/ptm/m/it` is substituted with `T3/ptm/m/sl`. However, that automatic substitution doesn't work on `T3/ptm/b/it`. But I can change my use of `\textit{\textbf{}}` to `\textsl{\textbf{}}` and that will take care of the issue.